# APC UPS Replacement Battery

Tags: battery, ups

I have an APC BE550G UPS with a battery which is 4 years old (the model is RBC110) and I would like to replace it. I believe the current battery capacity is 7AH, and I was thinking of replacing it with a 10AH aftermarket version. Is this ok or is it better to use a 7AH version like the one that came with it? I have been reading that with higher capacities the UPS can overheat since it does not have a fan to cool it. I also have never tried using non-OEM batteries before so I am not sure if that would be a good idea or not.

Comment: I do not recommend to use non-OEM battery for APC UPSs. With such battery UPS cannot correctly detect current percentage of battery charge and so may use charging regime nonconfortable for the battery. This may overheat and damage the battery, and backward UPS may detect that the battery is wrong whereas it is operable yet. The probability of UPS damage while using such battery is low.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a very similar APC unit here for my home office. I have replaced the battery set once. I suggest you use the correct replacement part to avoid possible issues. The larger capacity may take more charging current than the unit is capable of delivering